# How to get an overall error bar from many parameter constraints (and their error bars)

Tags: confidence-interval, error, uncertainty

I have a bunch of estimates of the same parameter. Each estimate has its own 68% CL errorbar. Is there a nice way to get a 1sigma error bar on all of the measurements? For example the gray band in this plot is what I'm after. Thanks! [image: For example the gray bar in this plot is what I'm after.]

Comment: You mean the vertical stripe?

Comment: @Dave Yes, the gray error band. Sorry for poor wording

Comment: How is that band produced?

Comment: @Dave That's what I'm asking